# Is there a Celery functionality analogous to RQ's worker burst?

Tags: python, task, celery, python-rq

[RQ provides a `.work(burst=True)`](http://python-rq.org/docs/testing/) method for its workers that are well-suited for integration tests, when you have code that enqueue's a task and then wants that task to be run synchronously.

I cannot find any functionality on [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/testing.html) that works like that. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `burst mode` in `celery`,
but there is a `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` option for testing:

> CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER
>
> If this is True, all tasks will be executed
> locally by blocking until the task returns. apply_async() and
> Task.delay() will return an EagerResult instance, which emulates the
> API and behavior of AsyncResult, except the result is already
> evaluated.
>
> That is, tasks will be executed locally instead of being sent to the
> queue.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#celery-always-eager